# Running into babel build error that I don't understand

Tags: webpack, compiler-errors, babeljs

I have been updating babel and have build fails for two files with the same error:

> TypeError: Property property of MemberExpression expected node to be
>   of a type ["Identifier","PrivateName"] but instead got null

I'm not sure what the issue is as they both appear to be correct and without syntax errors. they are in a form similar to the below code with implementation details left out:

```
export const funcName = () => {
  const someMethod = () => "someFunctionality";
  return {
    someMethod,
  };
};
export default funcName;
```

Since the code is correct, it makes me think something else might be the cause, but I'm at a loss. Has anyone encountered this error or know how to get passed it? I'm not sure what other details may be relevant so if I'm leaving anything out please let me know.

package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.0",
    "@babel/cli": "7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.26.0",
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/env",
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "transform-es2015-destructuring",
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might be using babel6 plugins with babel7.
Try using [@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-destructuring.html) and [@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread.html)